# Master page not loading when Razor MVC project deployed to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, iis-7, master-pages

I created a standard MVC Razor 4 web app, with .Net 4 selected (as the target IIS server only has .net 4 on it).

When I deploy it there was no CSS styling, so I dug a little deeper. On inspection of the HTML served up the master page is missing and only the inner content is served up.

### HTML is missing the master page:

```
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        ...
    </li>

    <li class="two">
        ...
    </li>
</ol>
```

basically it renders like a partial page.

I gather this is probably a permissions/security issue, but the only thing I could find (setting the anonymous credentials to Application Pool Identity) does not make a difference.

### Followup:

If I add `everyone` to the file permissions of the ISS folder it works, but what is the correct level of control and how should it be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it... The local user account had not been added to the new IIS website folder.

*Sigh*